# how do you integrate a save/publish invoked from excel to asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel-2007

I've been probing around and have not found any hits nor do I have a lot of experience with this topic.  I would like to open an excel document (ideally from an asp.net mvc model) and then post this model back to an asp.net mvc controller action for a save/publish through the application.

I would prefer to stay away from excel storing directly to the database, opting instead to go through the mvc action in order to adjust cache, run business rules, etc.

Any tips on places to look or how this is done?  I know TFS 2010 does this fine as does sharepoint but I'm not aware of the underlying technologies.

Thank you in advance!!
Jim

Comment: Jim, do you want to open the excel document on the server or open it up for the user and have a macro or similar within the Excel document post? some data back to the mvc-app? The scenario is a bit unclear so if you would be so kind and elaborate just a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm looking to open it up on the users desktop.  I'm looking into the Office Ribbon solutions within VS 2010 currently and fumbling around there.  My approach is to connect a custom button within a new ribbon and have it communicate to my app via WCF endpoints.  This is similar to the 'Team' ribbon that TFS inserts into Excel for the Publish/Refresh buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research it is apparent the answer to this lies in the VSTO libraries.  Initially I had a hurdle in place with our virus scanner which would not allow me to build a custom ribbon giving 'access denied' when attempting to load in my .dll's.

Beyond this, the API is fairly straightforward for adding a custom ribbon which has access to WCF, among any other .NET APIs within Excel (or any office tool).  This WCF service can invoke the MVC Controllers, if required, or directly perform business logic themselves - the sky's the limit.